Bijection between projective space and rational points of projective scheme
Let $k$ be a field. A $k$-scheme $(X,O_X)$ is a scheme such that $O_X(X)$ is a $k$-algebra. A rational point of a $k$-scheme $(X,O_X)$ is a point $x\in X$ such that there is a $k$-algebra isomorphism $O_{X,x}\to k$. The subset of rational points of a $k$-scheme $(X,O_X)$ is denoted by $X(k)\subset X$.
Let for this paragraph $(X,O_X)$ be the affine $n$-dimensional $k$-scheme $(\mathbb A^n_k,O_{\mathbb A^n_k})$. There is a bijection from the set $k^n$ to $\mathbb A^n_k(k)$, and I see that, for any ideal $I\subset k[T_1,\dots,T_n]$, this bijection restricts to a bijection from the set $Z(I)$ to $V(I)\cap \mathbb A^n_k(k)$. As usual $Z(I)\subset k^n$ is the subset where all polynomials in $I$ vanish, and $V(I)\subset \mathbb A^n_k$ is the set of prime ideals in $k[T_1,\dots,T_n]$ containing $I$.
Now let $(X,O_X)$ be the projective $n$-dimensional $k$-scheme $(\mathbb P^n_k,O_{\mathbb P^n_k})$. I see that there is a bijection from the usual projective space $\mathbb Pk^n$ to $\mathbb P^n_k(k)$, but I don't see how, for any homogeneous ideal $I\subset k[T_0,\dots,T_n]$, this bijection restricts to a bijection from the set $Z_+(I)$ to $V_+(I)\cap \mathbb P^n_k(k)$. Here $Z_+(I)\subset \mathbb Pk^n$ is the subset where all polynomials in $I$ vanish, and $V_+(I)\subset \mathbb P^n_k$ is the set of homogeneous prime ideals in $k[T_0,\dots,T_n]$ containing $I$ and not containing $(T_0,\dots T_n)$.
In particular the bijection $\mathbb Pk^n\to \mathbb P^n_k(k)$ sends a point $\mathbf a=(a_0:\dots : a_n)$ to the ideal $I_\mathbf a:= \sum_{0\le i,j\le n}(a_iX_j-a_jX_i)$. Hence I can reduce to prove that, given a homogeneous polynomial $f\in k[T_0,\dots,T_n]$, the condition $f(a_0,\dots a_n)=0$ at $\mathbf a\in \mathbb Pk^n$ is equivalent to the condition $f\in I_\mathbf a$.
My idea: if $f(a_0,\dots a_n)=0$ at $\mathbf a\in \mathbb Pk^n$, then $f\in \sum _{0\le i\le n} (T_i-a_i)$. Notice that, depending on the choice of the elements $a_0,\dots a_n\in k$ representing $\bf a$, the ideal $ \sum _{0\le i\le n} (T_i-a_i)$ varies, but since $f$ is homogeneous it is always true that $f\in  \sum _{0\le i\le n} (T_i-a_i)$. If I could prove that the homogeneous elements in the ideal $ \sum _{0\le i\le n} (T_i-a_i)$ generate precisely $I_\mathbf a$, for any choice of the $a_0,\dots a_n\in k$, then I would prove that $f\in I_\mathbf a$, since $f$ is homogeneous.
The converse implication $f(a_0,\dots a_n)$ at $\bf a$ if $f\in I_\mathbf a$ is instead trivial, but I am stuck with trying to to prove the italic part of the idea above.

Your definition of a $k$-scheme is incorrect. $\mathcal{O}_X$ should be a sheaf of $k$-algebras.

I find it easier to answer this question a different way. First, you have an incorrect definition of a $k$-point - the correct definition is that for a $k$-scheme $X\to\operatorname{Spec} k$, a point $x\in X$ is a $k$-point iff the natural map $k\to \kappa(x)$, from $k$ to the residue field at $x$, is an isomorphism. (The definition in your post would call only isolated copies of $\operatorname{Spec} k$ as $k$-points, which would mean that $\Bbb A^1_k$ has no $k$-points, for instance.) Once you have this corrected definition, you may simply observe that if $\varphi:Z\to X$ is an immersion, then the map on residue fields $k(\varphi(z))\to k(z)$ is an isomorphism, so any $k$-point of $X$ is also a $k$-point of any immersed subscheme.

If you would like to show that $f(a_0,\cdots,a_n)=0$ for $f$ homogeneous of positive degree implies that $f\in I_a$, then assume without loss of generality that $a_0=1$ (as some $a_i$ must be nonzero, so we can relabel so that $a_0\neq 0$, and $f(a_0,\cdots,a_n)=a_0^{\deg f} f(a_0/a_0,\cdots,a_n/a_0)$, so $f(a_0,\cdots,a_n)=0$ iff $f(1,a_1/a_0,\cdots,a_n/a_0)=0$; also, $I_a=I_{a'}$ if $a'$ is a different representative of $a$). Now I claim that any homogeneous polynomial $g$ of degree $d$ can be written as an element in $I$ plus $cX_0^d$ for some $c\in K$.
Proof: by induction on $d$. The case $d=0$ is clear: if $f=c$ is a constant polynomial, $f=0+c$. If $d>0$, we can write a monomial in $g$ as $\lambda X_j\cdot M$ for $M$ a monomial of degree $d-1$, and then $\lambda X_j\cdot M = \lambda (X_j-a_jX_0) M + \lambda a_j X_0 M$, where the first term of the RHS is in $I_a$ and the second term is a product of $X_0$ and a monomial of degree $d-1$. Doing this process for each monomial in $g$, we can write $g$ as a sum of an element of $I_a$ and $X_0$ times a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d-1$, and we're done by induction. $\blacksquare$
So if $f$ evaluates to $0$ at $a$, then writing $f=\psi+cX_0^d$ for $\psi\in I_a$, $c\in k$, and $d=\deg f$ by the above, we see that evaluating at $a$, we must have $c=0$, giving that $f\in I_a$. (There are plenty of other ways to do this - depending on what version of the projective nullstellensatz you know, you could reference that, or you could go to the affine cone and reference the affine nullstellensatz, or you could calculate on affine opens, etc. I chose this version because it's not so long and it's reasonably self-contained.)
